# Upgrade Vista Home Premium to Windows 7 Home Premium - will I lose recorded TV?

Tags: windows-7, tv, dvr-ms

I'm seriously considering upgrading to Windows 7 on release, especially now that the [UK price for doing so is actually reasonable for once](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/technology/8118749.stm), but am worried about losing the ~600GB of TV that I have recorded.  AFAIK the recording format changed from the RTM Vista code when the TV Pack (Fiji?) was introduced to OEMs a while back and it is not possible to convert existing recordings to the new format.

I'm assuming that 7 builds on the TV Pack code, so will upgrading lose me all my recorded TV?

Comment: You'll have to back up the files to an external source (I don't trust the Windows.old thing!), since an upgrade is not possible with the UK versions of Windows 7. It has to be a full reinstall of the operating system.

Comment: All the TV is on a 1TB drive used only for data, so this is no problem.  When I said 'upgrade' I was meaning only in the sense of an up-rev in Windows version - no way would I risk importing any of Vista's pre-SP2 flakiness to a virgin W7 install!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Media Center in 7 saves recorded shows as .wtv files but it can still read the older .dvr-ms format that Vista used (without the TVPack).

Answer (score 0):

Can't find a source, but it would be really (yes really) stupid if they would make it incompatible with your files recorded with Vista, since that would make it a showstopper for people upgrading their Media Center. Plus I think the upgrade wouldn't overwrite any of your media files.

Guess you don't have 600 Gb of backup space to see and find out?

Edit: are you using TV Pack for Vista already? I think the largest change is for users who don't have it already and compatibility problems are most likely to be for Vista users trying to play files made with the new format, not the other way around.

Comment: No, I held off trying the TV Pack hack as it seemed likely that I would lose the recorded TV.

Microsoft? Stupid?  Nawwww... ;)

Comment: Well I still think you'll be able to play it, but once you update you can't go back. So your new recordings won't be playable under your old version. From what I read I understand TV Pack was very unstable when it was launched, but from what I read in the Engadget review I think those problems are all gone now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't directly upgraded my Media Center HTPC from Vista to 7 yet, but I upgraded a laptop, and was able to view Recorded TV shared from the HTPC.

Answer (score 0):

If the video is in a standard format (mpg, mov, wmp, flv, avi, etc) it will continue to work.

Comment: The stream is held in a format called DVR-MS

Comment: Then the answer is yes. In build 7000 they didn't play back, but that was due to a bug which was resolved in January.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961367